# How do I view iCloud Calendar in Windows

Tags: windows-8, calendar, ios, icloud

I'm on Windows 8, and just want to view my iCloud (iPhone/iPad) Calendars on my computer, somehow. I'm not a huge fan of the icloud.com site, and would much prefer if I could see my iCloud calendars in Google Calendar since that is my primary use.

I could use Outlook but the iCloud plugin makes going to the calendar view slow

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use icloud.com to view and edit your calendar.
2. You can also use the iCloud Control Panel (free) to allow push (not periodic) sync to Outlook, which also gives you view and edit access.
3. You can make any of your calendars public (unwise if you're keeping personal data in them) and share the webcal:// link with a third party app (e.g., Google Calendar or Outlook), but it's only refreshed periodically and is read-only.